# Get search engine referrer using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a question, haven't tested it but want to check things first.

I'm using wordpress currently with a cache plugin, to avoid caching parts of the page, I use ajax and include what I need in another page that is not cached.

My question is, is it possible to use ajax to include a php file and read the search engine referrer?

I'm thinking that maybe when using ajax, you get your own page as a referrer for that included php file using ajax. Or am I wrong in thinking this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you not just want `document.referrer`?

Comment: in fact I think you're right, and pass a variable to the ajax call, right?

Comment: Whatever you want to do with it, yeah :)

Comment: What do you mean by "search engine referrer"? But yes, when you use ajax the request will only pass the site that send the ajax request.